# Primal form of Soft margin SVM implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, kernel, svm

I am implementing primal form of soft margin svm. After calculating the weight and bias parameters, I need to test it on test data. How can I achieve that? I need to calculate the accuracy of the test data classification. Thank you.

Thank you.

Comment: Compare the classification you got against reference data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classification rule of your SVM is (no matter if you trained it in soft or hard margin rule):

```
cl(x) = sign(<w, x> - b) = sign( SUM_i w_i x_i - b )
```

where w_i are your coefficients and b is a bias.

Just take your test set, pass it through this rule and calculate the fraction of correct predictions (accuracy).

Comment: I did the same thing. But I am confused that if the sign is -ve, then the sample is misclassified else it is correctly classified. But how to compare that classification (correct or incorrect) with the test classification given ??

Comment: This equation assigns label, it does not compare anything. In order to train SVM you need binary labeled data - usually with "+1" and "-1", you train the model and later on use the equation provided to assign predicted labels to each test point. Then in order to compute accuracy you just count how many times you predicted the correct label (the same as in the test set) and divide by total number of elements in test set.

Comment: What is "-ve" in your comments?

Comment: My questions is this:

In the above equation we just apply the trained model to test data and find labels. If its -ve then it is misclassified else it is correctly classified. In the test dataset I have its correct output labels as -1 or 1. But if the data point is classified correctly, how can i find out whether its output is 1 or -1?

Comment: You seem to not understand the basic concepts here. The equation I gave **does not check correctness**, this gives you **predicted label**, actual label. You have your test points, these are pairs (x, y), where y is either -1 or +1, you check if cl(x) == y, and if it does - you increase correctness count by 1 and you do not otherwise, that's all.